# Open colorbox from string

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I am new to jquery and haven’t spend much time with JavaScript either. What I am trying to achieve is to create a function that open a colorbox based on the inparameter. So basically you call the function and the colorbox opens.

```
function openWindow(textstring) { 
    $(textstring).colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
};
```

Comment: I don't think `colorbox` is a built-in jQuery function. Which plugin are you using?

Comment: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function openWindow(textstring) { 
    $.colorbox({html:textstring});
};
```

works, I saw it on their official page. Had looked at the same page yesterday but probably didn’t saw it because of my limited jquery syntax knowledge. Wasn’t meant to answer my own question.

Comment: your answer does not seem to fit to your question. Maybe it will be better to edit your answer, clarify what you wanted to ask so that future visitors will learn from this question and answer.